# _Orphan_range crash when using static vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

In my project, I use the constructor of a static object to collect pointers, like a registration method. Very simply, no magic. But during the start I experience a crash, and I can't explain what's happening here. The crash is reproducible on Windows with MSVC or Clang, both using the MSVC headers. Given is the following simple example. Can anyone give me a hint why this could cause issues?

This code seems to work just fine in GCC and Clang on Linux:

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vSKdpW

## bar.cpp

```
static int bar = 1;

static Registration abc(&bar);
```

## foo.cpp

```
static std::vector<void*> registrations;

void add_to_array(void* p)
{
    registrations.push_back(p);
}
```

## foo.h

```
class Registration
{
public:
    Registration(void* op)
    {
        add_to_array(op);
    }
};
```

Executing results in the following crash (**_Pnext** was 0x8.)

```
void _Orphan_range(pointer _First, pointer _Last) const { // orphan iterators within specified (inclusive) range
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);

    _Iterator_base12** _Pnext = &_Mypair._Myval2._Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
    while (*_Pnext) {    <=======================   **_Pnext** was 0x8.
```

Does anyone know why a static vector can't be used to simply collect pointers to objects? `foo.cpp` is the only file that uses the vector with `push_back`. The array is not modified anywhere else.

Comment: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order.html

Comment: Related, but it doesn't matter which one gets initialized before. The vector was in the r/o field of the binary and should be well initialized

Comment: Even a bool flag to initialize it on first push doesn't solve the issue

Comment: I too subscribe to the *static initialization problem*. I think the boolean test would be irrelevant, as it would fall under the same conditions as the vector itself. I wasn't able to reproduce it with *VStudio 2017*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having debugged a similar issue just now using VS2019 runtime, I'll go ahead and say this is almost assuredly caused by a zero initialized (but not constructed) vector.

The forensics, in my case, looked like this: the value of `_Pnext` was `0x8` because `_Myproxy` is null. With `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` set to 2 (i.e.: in Debug profile), `_Myproxy` gets dereferenced, leading to this crash, but Release won't crash since that code is skipped altogether.

Now, looking at MSVC142/VS2019's implementation of vector, you'll see that every single constructor calls `_Alloc_proxy`, which is what allocates some memory for `_Myproxy` and assigns the value. So if the constructor had been invoked, you would've necessarily have a non-null `_Myproxy`.

Static initialization in C++ occurs in two steps: zero initialization, followed by static initialization in an arbitrary, linker determined order. It appears that in the order you end up with, Foo.cpp's `Registration` gets constructed before Bar.cpp's `registrations` vector, effectively calling `push_back` on a zero initialized (but not constructed) vector.

So as the comments suggested, you should definitely rearrange your static initialization so that your vector is properly constructed before using it.

*(In my case, I was allocating memory for a struct containing a vector, but not calling placement `operator new` on that memory. To anyone else finding this question like I did, look for any source of a zeroed but not constructed vector.)*