# _Orphan_range crash when using static vector (another example of)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdvector, c++20

For DEBUG builds in MS Visual Studio 2019, Ver. 16.10.0, Toolset v142,
I got with the code below an exception: 'read access violation' in _Orphan_range_unlocked()
(possibly very similar to what is discussed here [1])

The problem does not occur for in older VS versions, in release builds or by using clang toolset.
However, because the crash only occurs in these very specific circumstances, I suspect there may be a bug in Visual Studio. Or is it a programming error after all?
I would like to understand this.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    // Exception: 'read access violation' in _Orphan_range_unlocked()
    // (in C++20 MSVC Debug builds but not in C++17 nor Release)

    static std::array<std::vector<int>, 4> arrvec;
    arrvec[0].reserve(3);
    arrvec[0].emplace_back(1);  // <- Exception occurs here
}
```

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62605686/15157143)

For this I opened a bug report here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1934

Comment: could you simplify the example further? for example removing the static vector and the using statement

Comment: @Alessandro Teruzzi: Of course. 
I have a) simplified the example and b) corrected: arrvec must be declared static to cause the exception.

Comment: I don't have a MSVC compiler that's why I am asking all this questions, could you strip something else from the example. Does it still fails if arrvec is not static? If not could you reproduce the issue with a static std::vector<int> directly?

Comment: It does not fail if arrvec is not static.
It does not fail with a std::vector<int> directly.
It does not fail with another toolset nor in release nor in C++17.
And: Most propably it may not fail in another compiler.

Comment: Interesting, you should report this to Microsoft.