# _Orphan_range crash in vector.push_back in debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdvector

I have a class with lots of members that uses `memset( this, 0, sizeof *this );` in the constructor to zero-initialize all its members. I am now trying to add a new member that is a `std::vector`. I am getting a runtime error at _Orphan_range with the following simplified code (only happens in debug mode on visual studio; I have not tested with any other compiler):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class C
{
public:
    std::vector<int> v;
    C() {
        memset(this, 0, sizeof * this);
        //v = std::vector<int>(); // adding this line solves the problem
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        c.v.push_back(i);
        std::cout << c.v[i];
    }
}
```

After reading a few other posts (https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1934, [_Orphan_range crash when using static vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61809337/orphan-range-crash-when-using-static-vector)) I realized that the issue can be solved by reinitializing the vector in the constructor (see the commented line in the constructor).

From what I read in the other posts, the issue may be a MSVC compiler bug that only happens in debug mode. I did not write the original class myself and I do not fully understand how `memset` works, so maybe there is something wrong with the class and the error is expected. However, I am puzzled by the fact that it works normally in release mode and that the error only occurs after the 5th iteration.

Is this a bug? Why does it only throw an error at the 5th iteration? Is my fix the best way get around this issue?

I am using Visual Studio 2022 with MSVC v143.

Comment: You are making the assumption that `std::vector` is a POD type ... but it probably isn't. In Debug mode, MSVC may add 'control' flags and data to the class that should **not** be initialized to zero. TL;DR Just use the (real) constructor to initialize STL objects.

Comment: initializing `std::vector` with `memset` is undefined behavior, so it's perfectly valid for your program to appear to work only in release mode.

Comment: Just get out of the habit of *ever* using code like `memset(this, 0, sizeof * this);`. It's (1) lazy and (2) likely to be the cause of vast quantities of pain ... especially when you start adding virtual functions to your class.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I agree that memset is not good practice. I just wanted to confirm this is not bug before taking the time to make a fix.